# Get character based on index in Python

Tags: python, string, indexing

I am fairly new to python and was wondering how do you get a character in a string based on an index number?

Say I have the string "hello" and index number 3.  How do I get it to return the character in that spot, it seems that there is some built in method that I just cant seem to find.

Comment: This is a very basic question. The answer can be easily here http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ You should read that before you do anything else

Answer (score 4):

You just need to index the string, just like you do with a list.

```
>>> 'hello'[3]
l
```

Note that Python indices (like most other languages) are zero based, so the first element is index 0, the second is index 1, etc.

For example:

```
>>> 'hello'[0]
h
>>> 'hello'[1]
e
```

Comment: not the best illustration because it doesn't make the origin obvious.  Saying that [1] is e would be better

Comment: @PeterWooster The OP *did* ask for index number 3, so I just used that. I also mention that the indices were zero based, but just added some examples to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

its just straight forward.

```
str[any subscript]. //e.g. str[0], str[0][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [this page](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)...

What you need is:

> Strings can be subscripted (indexed); like in C, the first character of a string has subscript (index) 0.
>   There is no separate character type; a character is simply a string of size one.
>   Like in Icon, substrings can be specified with the slice notation: two indices separated by a colon.

**Example**:

```
>>> word[4]
'A'
>>> word[0:2]
'He'
>>> word[2:4]
'lp'
```

---

For your case try this:

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> s[3]
'l'
```